# Rust build (cargo build) using Powershell causes error but builds file

Tags: powershell, rust, azure-devops

rust 1.65.0
I have a rust build where I just do a Cargo Build. Everything seems fine (including the build) but at the top of the output has an error about updating crates.io index. No other place has in the output shows an error. However, this error causes my ADO pipeline to fail.

My call from ADO Task (Inline Powershell):

```
Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\avmh\avmh"
cargo build --release
```

Start of output:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\c3cde96b-7741-41cd-a0f8-bf936f4b9d7d.ps1'"
##[error]Updating crates.io index
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded anyhow v1.0.66
  Downloaded hmac v0.12.1
  Downloaded proc-macro-error v1.0.4
  Downloaded regex-automata v0.1.10
.
.
.
   Compiling avmh v0.4.0 (D:\a\1\s\src\avmh\avmh)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 10m 08s
Finishing: Build AVMH
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with how you're running `cargo build` since the powershell stuff and final line are not part of it's output. But perhaps the "Updating crates.io index" is emitted using stderr and the `##[error]` is an attempt at annotating that from your runner.

Comment: I am not using any runner other than a Powershell inline ADO Task. I literally just have the path to the src code and run 'cargo build' from that directory.  Here is my call:# Run simple build of AVMH
 Set-Location "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\avmh\avmh"
cargo build --release

Comment: Does ADO mean Azure DevOps? If so, you're using the wrong tag. The answers [here](/q/52168432/2189130) and [here](/q/63736159/2189130) may help you if my hunch is correct.

Comment: Yes - ADO is Azure Dev Ops. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The big issue is this "##[error]Updating crates.io index" line in the rust output. I only see this when running as an ADO pipeline.  One thing to note - it does go through and actually builds all the necessary files. The problem is since it sees that Update crates.io index as an error, the pipeline returns a fail. I just don't know Rust \ Crates.io enough to know cause of this.